# How to change writeConcern in MongoDB through shell?

Tags: mongodb

I am able to change default write concern ie ACKNOWLEDGE via JAVA client.

But, how to change writeConcern in MongoDB while inserting a document through shell? Is is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update operations can accept a `writeConcern` document.

Insert example:

```
db.collection.insert(
    { x : 1 },
    { writeConcern: { w: 2 } }
)
```

Update example:

```
db.collection.update(
    { x : 1 },
    { $set : { y : 2 } },
    { upsert: true, writeConcern: { w:1, j:true } }
)
```

Remove example:

```
db.collection.remove(
    { x : 1 },
    { writeConcern: { wtimeout: 5000 } }
)
```

Comment: I tried insert. It is showing syntax error:  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: It should work. It may be that you are using V 2.4 which didn't include write concern. Also, `{w : 2}` should work only if you are using a replica set.

Comment: Sorry, its error from my end. I tested with 3.0. It's working fine.